# Can a link in a hal/json element return a 404?

Tags: json, hal-json

Im implementing a hal/json api.

The root object (soldier) has a related object (sword), that is mapped under `/soldier/{object_id}/sword`

```
{
  "id": 12345,
  "name": "Sir SmokeALot",
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://soldier.local:8080/soldier/12345"
    },
    "sword": {
      "href": "http://soldier.local:8080/soldier/12345/sword"
    }
  }
}
```

But not every soldier has a sword. Imagine the poor soldier without a sword.

1. if i retrieve the `soldier`-object, should the link `/soldier/{object_id}/sword` appear in the `_links`-array?
2. And if it should, what would i get back from this link? An empty object or a 404? Is it even allowed by hal/json RFC to have links in the `_links`-array that lead to a 404?

I don't ask how to solve this, i want to know *whats right*.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, I think you wouldn't even publish the link if a soldier doesn't have a sword (if it's not expensive to calculate). Returning HttpStatusCode 404 leaves no room for interpretation in my opinion, unlike an "empty object" (whatever that would be). I also don't see any issues with a link leading to a 404, but the proposed [draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kelly-json-hal-03#section-8.2) specification might be interpreted otherwise ([RFC 5988](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988#section-5.2) also seems to have info on this).

I don't think you'll find very strict, strongly enforced rules in the area of RESTful HAL, more like guidelines, there's rarely right or wrong, black or white, more like shades of grey - just find out what works for you and establish a clear contract for your clients.

Comment: well, its not that easy to not publish a link, since then you dont know that this object _may_ exist, and you cant store something there without that link. The default behaviour of Spring Data Rest seems to be giving back a 404 link in this situation.